# How to monitor the list of users who are using google apps email

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-analytics

As a google apps administrator, How to monitor the list of users who are using google apps email (say over the weekend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try logging into Google Apps and checking the Reports tab.

Example:

```
https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/mydomain.com/Reports#Reports
```

[image]

Details on how your users access Email can be checked by clicking on `Additional reports`

[image]

If the image text is not readable:

> The email clients report explains how users in your domain access their hosted accounts on a day-by-day basis. For each day, the report lists the total number of accounts in your domain as well as the number and percentage of users who accessed their accounts using WebMail. This report does not include suspended accounts in the account total.

Comment: I don't see an "Additional Reports" section in my UI, where is it?

Comment: Where are you looking?

Comment: I was able to find it, but I need information on login activity which I couldn't find from any of the available ones.

Comment: I think the information you'r looking for is present in the Google Apps Reports section. Just double check.

Comment: I need information like user1 logged in at 10 AM, user2 logged in at 11 AM ...

Comment: Yes you can get the last login date, last login time, last web-mail time. You could monitor this regularly to get your info. I don't think Google or anyone would share an explicit history. it would be go against your user's privacy.

Comment: Since I am the Google Apps admin, I would like to monitor for people registered within this organization.